# Atleast ONE Space around Parenthesis in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

I want spaces around **Parenthesis** in **IF condition**. ATleast one space is required. But when i use Space in grammar it throws me error, **when i use Else block with it**. Please help me, how to accomplish it, i have seen many examples but none is related to it.
i only need spaces around **Parenthesis** of **If condition**.

```
prog: stat_block EOF;

stat_block: OBRACE block CBRACE;

block: (stat (stat)*)?;

stat: expr ';'
 | IF  condition_block (ELSE  stat_block)?
 ;

expr
 : expr SPACE ('*' | '/') SPACE expr
 | ID
 | INT
 | STRING
 ;

 exprList: expr (',' expr)*;

 condition_block: SPACE OPAR SPACE expr SPACE CPAR SPACE stat_block;
 IF:      'IF';
 ELSE:    'ELSE';
 OPAR:    '(';
 CPAR:    ')';
 OBRACE:  '{';
 CBRACE:  '}';
 SPACE: SINGLE_SPACE+;
 SINGLE_SPACE: ' ';
 ID:      [a-zA-Z]+;
 INT:     [0-9]+;
 NEWLINE: '\r'? '\n'  -> skip;
 WS:      [ \t]+     -> skip;
```

Expected input to parse

```
IF ( 3 ) { } ELSE { }
```

Current Input
[image]

Comment: You can't skip spaces and then still require them in certain places of the grammar. In some situations it may make sense to use lexical modes to only sometimes skip spaces, but that does not apply to your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a reason that almost all languages ignore whitespace.  If you don't ignore it, then you have to deal with its possible existence in the token stream anywhere it might, or might not, be in ALL of your parser rules.

You *can* try to include the spaces in the Lexer rules for tokens that you want wrapped in spaces, but may still find surprises.

Suggestion:  Instead if `-> skip;` for your `WS` rule, use `-> channel(HIDDEN);` This keeps the tokens in the token stream so you can look for them in your code, but "hides" the whitespace tokens from the parser rules.  This also allows ANTLR to get a proper interpretation of your input and build a parse tree that represents it correctly.

If you **REALLY** want to insist on the spaces before/after, you can write  code in a listener that looks before/after the tokens in the input stream to see if you have whitespace, and generate your own error (that can be very specific about your requirement).

Comment: I have adjusted my parser accordingly and removed spaces from grammar. Thanks for pointing this out, what is doable and what is not.

Answer (score 2):

> At least one space is required.

Then you either:

- cannot `-> skip` the `WS` rule, which will cause *all* spaces and tabs to become tokens and needing your parser to handle them correctly (which is likely going to become a complete mess in your parser rules!), or
- you leave `WS -> skip` as-is, but include a space in your `PAREN` rules: `OPAR : ' ( '; CPAR: ' ) ';` (or with tabs as well if that is possible)

Comment: Second option did work out but error message i was getting from antlr was not user friendly. and for the first option, thanks for explaining , how it works.